# Is it possible to install mono or similar (C# compiler like AIDE) on android machine?

Tags: c#, android, mono

I was searching for a while, but didn't get the solution.

If you want to write mobile applications with c#, you can install mono as I understand.
It can be found on the following site http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid
.

So they support both Windows and IOS.
But I think they don't support to run their software on android

My question is: 
Is there any tool to write code with c# on an android device?

I mean I want to write C# code and compile directly on my android device.

I know AIDE for java, but it seems there isn't exist any tool like AIDE for C#

Thank you..

Comment: You're seriously guessing that a product called "Mono for Android" only supports Windows and iOS?

Comment: Yes I am guessing please correct me if it is false, "Mono for Android" can be installed on Windows and Macs to build "Android" applications. You can check the Mono for Android Site. Here is the Link: [http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Guides/Getting_Started/Installation](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Guides/Getting_Started/Installation) There are only two options which are: 1st Windows and 2nd Mac. So there isn't any opportunity to install the application on android as a 3rd option...

Comment: That's a lot clearer than your question. They do of course support Android, just not as an installation platform. (And keep in mind that iOS is not MacOS X. It cannot be installed on iOS either.) More relevant to your question, Mono for Android cannot do what you want directly, but if you have a C# compiler, written in C#, you can use Mono for Android to run that compiler on Android. Will give more details when I can.

Answer (score 4):

The `Mono for Android` project allows you to write code in C# and run it on the Android platform. It will install a Mono runtime along with your app.

The Mono runtime run along side the Dalvik virtual machine, so performance is comparable to writing your app in Java and running it inside of Dalvik.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but I think I don't not understand it clearly. Can **Mono for Android** installed on an Android Operating System? (If it is true, then it makes possible to write C# code and compile it on the same Android Device) (AIDE makes it real for Java. You can check the link [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui) )

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're asking now. No, `Mono for Android` cannot "be installed" on android. It is a framework for compiling C# apps to Android. As far as I know there's nothing like `AIDE` for C#.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [C# To Go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gregshackles.csharptogo), a simple C# compiler that runs on Android. The Mono C# compiler has been ported to Mono for Android for it, and [that port](https://github.com/gshackles/runcs) is also available for you to use.

Note that the compiler is not perfect. [Introducing C# To Go](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/07/introducing-c-to-go-a-c-compiler-for-android/) details some of the problems you may face. Nevertheless, it may be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a tool like AIDE where you can write code in C# on Android, compile on Android, and deploy to the same device. Such a tool would have to come from Xamarin as they hold the IP and sell licenses for MonoDroid.

Comment: Thank you but AIDE is for Java, I would like to know is there any tool exists like AIDE for C# in android. Aide Web AddressÇ [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui) you can check and watch videos to see it in action. Thank you.